# Type 'recordedVideoLibraryEntry | null' is not assignable to type 'recordedVideoLibraryEntry'

Tags: typescript

this is the interface

```
    export interface recordedVideoLibraryEntry {
  recordingId: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  timestamp: string;
  video: any;
}
```

i try to get value from localStorage and assign to recordedVideoLibraryEntry

```
export const updateRecordingDetails = async (data) => {
  const {
    recordingId,
    name,
    description,
    timestamp,
    video,
  }: recordedVideoLibraryEntry = await library.getItem(data.recordingId);

  const entry: recordedVideoLibraryEntry = {
    recordingId,
    name: data.name || name,
    timestamp,
    description: data.description || description,
    video,
  };

  await library.setItem(recordingId, entry);
};
```

then i got following error

```
    Type 'recordedVideoLibraryEntry | null' is not assignable to type 'recordedVideoLibraryEntry'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'recordedVideoLibraryEntry'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: That tell you that `library.getItem` is defined as returning `Promise<recordedVideoLibraryEntry | null>` (or `recordedVideoLibraryEntry | null` if you're using `await` unnecessarily). So that's what you need to fix.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you for reply. i have  updated question. please can you check it again

Comment: I don't see anything in the update that suggests that the return value of `getItem` isn't as I described above, which -- again -- is the problem. You have to allow for the `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@T.J. Crowder is right that you need to be checking for possible `null` values returned by `library.getItem`.

(Sidenote: Typescript actually says that `WindowLocalStorage['localStorage']['getItem']` can only return `string` or `null`, but I don't know if that's accurate.  Is it returning your object, or are you JSON encoding/decoding it?)

While we're doing that, let's also remove some unnecessary destructuring and restructuring, since we're only changing two properties.

Let's also require that `data` has a `recordingId`, since we can't call `getItem` without it.  `name` and `description` seem to be optional.  Your type definition should change if these can have values like `null`.  I'm assuming they are either present and valid or totally absent.

FYI this is not a requirement, but it's a convention that types and interfaces uses upper case names.

```
export const updateRecordingDetails = async (
    data: Pick<RecordedVideoLibraryEntry, 'recordingId'> & Partial<RecordedVideoLibraryEntry>
): Promise<void> => {

    const foundEntry = await library.getItem(data.recordingId);

    if (foundEntry === null) {
        // return an error?
    }

    else {
        // now know that it is not null

        // copy all properties of foundEntry, then override two
        const entry: RecordedVideoLibraryEntry = {
            ...foundEntry,
            name: data.name || foundEntry.name,
            description: data.description || foundEntry.description,
        };

        // note: data.recordingId and foundEntry.recordingId should be the same, 
        // but I'm not sure which you want to use here in the rare case of a mismatch error.
        // you could even throw an error on mismatch and not update either
        await library.setItem(foundEntry.recordingId, entry);
    }
};
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAmFMGMBsEMCdwAJIHsB2BnALk6BLAI3gQE8AuJAdX3VFQHcAZVSWaAZW1RIHNwA2gHJordlx6x%20QgLoBuALAAoZRBgJkaLLgLEylJkRLxSilUvAAPAA49ctbOHgAzWJGQAlKDwigAavgQqIZ6JgCi6NgmSADeykgJSIho8KC0vACSoJQ48OlmiUjosAC24DlR%20fGJEJiQedbY%20BgVeei8BYlNZTil1q1VSoUAboHgqJSw6KbKAL7Kyla28PaRTq7uSCHGpLHVCfzYGY4lABTJPulZA%200AlJQACvCoJfiY4AA8Xim%20AUHbZAiUV2AB8igBXaDQAB8nQS7yOJ3O3lSV2ySFy6QANEhwJETJRvj5wP4xsEjID8aR7kgni83p9hqhArC5gsLDY7CgMDgkODrKBYI4iaj2gARcDYWD4aCYJAAXiQsEwpHQkCQp32SEFUse%20EgAGsvijfmSAeEqTihBdRZlQEJoUgAGS0hBNdjGn4kv7jc2kIEmaHKGl017vD5MlkKx1xcyFLS85yocF0AO7RWwBjSnQUkwAOkOx3AZx1sDzNrS7SytzMWvwzg1SZToDTCvlivQkOgtz2Q0KiRASUl4Pg6CVY6cz3gAH4tfM44lwLLkLH%20wPgEVGEgDegt9gABZCpD4exy3e4TtQ9lrhKDtDWXbsaBIazPaxOJrgOWoBtN1OWpADzxJBUGGScxkAhhUC1eMeVwPFgUJE1vTNXN-SpBVexvfs81wv8W0tGCb2KMpKFLPMSOQEEwXwtMKNKcAsSItdanqfBGmadAyKFMtWIaJoMCQaikFoqk8z49iBPQJi%20zXWZa1k-tB3PcptR48sTTRcdQBE5N-2BDSfi0zB92TaAdMIZAgIxBicWYpBB0IcFcAyIQSk3XBMBHZAGH3fV9yQUhkyQLNIkA1A%20XeJB9ycZBaEAmKkg0FBlWQH8lSQMMSiFSAAsnHg83swcgvBblIR08AwLHA9ngYcdcXgKcQLHLKcoCqYdPPPkBSFZBwBPGL4HszNszwNC8wRIszlEgyKzRHEEJMGs5zmOQgA)